# How to write TXT file to sdcard?

Tags: java, android, logfile

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File logfile = new File(path, "andrometer.txt");
String[] assignArr = new String [7];

assignArr[0]= finalValue + "17";
assignArr[1]= range + "16";
assignArr[2]= activeMode;

if (assignArr.length > 0)
{
    try {
        if (path.canWrite()){
            FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(logfile);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
            for (int i1=0; i1<assignArr.length; i1++)
            {
                out.write(assignArr[0] + "\n");
                out.write(assignArr[1] + "\n");
                out.write(assignArr[2] + "\n");
                Toast.makeText(AndroMeter.this, "out: " + assignArr[2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
    }
};
```

This code was working a couple weeks ago and now I can't seem to get it to. I have the permission in the manifest correctly I believe, I tried writing to root instead of specific folder, I've been testing with dummy data in place of the variable names. No file is being created at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing:

```
FileOutputStream fo=new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/filename");
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.